# "The Sun Management Center server is being initialized. Retry?" error on SunMC 4.0 console

Tags: solaris, sun, solaris-10

I have installed the SunMC on my V490 server. And after the es-inst, es-setup, when I run the "es-start -c" it will show the login screen. After I login, it will hang on the "Welcome to Sun Management Center" window and after a long while will pop up an alert message saying "The Sun Management Center server is being initialized. Retry?" When I click "Retry" it will hang for the same amount of time then pop up again. When I click "Cancel" it will quit out of the console.

Server is running Solaris 10, java 1.5.0_12. I even ran the "es-config -r" suggested by Halcyon site but still no luck. What would be the cause of this problem and how should I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Please post your "svcs -a" command output

make sure wbem service is up and running by typing

```
svcs wbem
```